# Note 4 Verizon Branded

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

I just activated my note 4 it's through Verizon but I switched it to AT&T and am now using it for cricket. Only problem is I want the Verizon boot logo off and all the Verizon based default apps and junk. How can I remove this from my phone permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Verizon and AT&T locks down the bootloader of its phones, usually killing possibilities of root and custom ROMs in the progress. Luckily it seems Note4 has an unlock solution (read [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-verizon/general/note-4-verizon-bootloader-unlock-t3358913) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4-verizon/development/howto-bootloader-unlock-upgrade-to-t3398144)), although it does require your current build to be old enough (Lollipop). After that, flash a custom recovery and a custom ROM and you're flying with no Verizon bullsh!t and generally better performance.

Comment: I believe I just watched a whole video on how to do this but i ran into a block on my windows 10. It wouldn't let me install samsung mobile phone drivers for some stupid reason! It just prompted me saying this publisher is blocked and I have everything set on the phone just right this thing is killing me.

Comment: Yeah it's exactly what I just tried, any advice on the blocking of the USB drivers? All it says is "this publisher is blocked from running software on your machine but it wont let me fix it I've tried turning the security off, I've gone to the link it gives me but it just brings me to the windows help center. And then it just starts giving me blocking messages saying it's been blocked.

Comment: @Frobinson8 Disable signature enforcement (i.e. enable test mode) from command prompt. You will see how to do it by searching (hint: involves bcdedit).

Comment: I keep trying different ways to stop the problems I run into, and when I fix them another problem occurs somewhere else. What about Verizon is making this more complicated than usual? Also when will easier methods come out? Also i tried to downgrade my device but i ran into problems, does it matter how far i downgrade? I also seem to keep having problems when dealing with my commands in cmd like im missing files or it cant find path to my phone.

Comment: also is there a really and i mean REALLY simple step by step walk-through tutorial on how to accomplish root and bootloader for the verizon note 4

Comment: What you get when you purchase stuff from AT&T/Verizon. It's already a miracle they come up with a way to unlock the bootloader unofficially. Don't think twice, just push yourself into doing it.